# Why same char is not equal

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I have a simple code.

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   if(Serial.available()) {
      char incomingChar = Serial.read();
      char testChar = ".";

      Serial.println(incomingChar);
      Serial.println(incomingChar == testChar);
   }
}
```

I opened serial monitor interface. I set baud to 9600 and "No line ending" and was typing: `a`, `b`, `.` output is:

```
14:38:35.675 -> a
14:38:35.675 -> 0
14:38:37.105 -> b
14:38:37.105 -> 0
14:38:38.557 -> .
14:38:38.557 -> 0
```

Why char `.` from serial port is not equal to `.`?

Comment: Change this `char testChar = ".";` to `char testChar = '.';`

Comment: `"."` isn't a `char`.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `testChar`? You might be surprised by what you see. Conclusion: enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Thank so much and sorry about noob question. `'.'` works.

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: The language that Arduino uses is C++, not C. It is quite significant when it comes to for example interpreting the behaviour of println and so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `"."` to `'.'`.

`""` means string not a char